# Dart/Flutter: How to refer to static variables on an abstract class?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, model

I am writing a Firestore Model abstract class that handles common operations. Each model matches a collection in Firestore... I want to refer to that both from a create instance and before the instance exists. But I can't make `collectionPath` static because I can't override static methods, variables, getters, etc... I get that.

Could create an instance as needed maybe `Model().collectionPath` but I couldn't get that to work.

Is there a way to do this? How are others making these types of Models?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
abstract class Model {
  String get collectionPath => "";

  void create() async {
    CollectionReference collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(this.collectionPath);
    this.reference = await collection.add(this.toMap());
  }

  static Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(this.collectionPath).snapshots();
  }
  //...
```

```
class User extends Model {
  String get collectionPath => "users";
  //...
```

I want to be able add an existing instance to the firestore:

```
User user = User("Values");
user.create();
```

And I'd also like to load all the users before I've created any particular one:

```
 Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: User.snapshots(),
```

Comment: why is model static?

Comment: Thx for response... just some of the methods/variables I want static, or someway to use them before a particular User exists. Such as the load snapshot of all models.